# How should i change connection string, for hosting asp.net site

Tags: asp.net, database, hosting, connection-string

```
   connectionString=Data        Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True providerName=System.Data.SqlClient
```

// what should i change in my connection string so i can host my asp.net site on aspspider.info...
//i get this errod

SqlException (0x80131904): User does not have permission to perform this action....and so on...

Comment: Please contact your hosting provider and I believe they will let you know the correct connection string. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dubaicargo;
Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=password;pooling=false
```

change your connection don't use integrated security. the above connection is just a sample. there are many ways to connect to yourdatabase with more security see [this](http://connectionstrings.com/) for list connection strings

Comment: <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

//i changed to this one and still doesn't change

Answer (score 1):

Try to use SqlServer Authentication instead of windows authentication